# Python - Analyze colors on image by given array of main colors

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, scipy

For image analysis I have to count pixels by X main colors (like red, yellow, brown, black), given in array (BGR format for OpenCV usage). I tried to achieve that using KMeans from scikit having predefined init array, but even with n_init=1 and max_iter=1 centers are updating. Sadly, I have to handle specific colors.

Are there any other switches to block init array from changing or different solutions to count pixels per predefined nearest neighbour?

I read many articles, still being unable to fulfil needs.

Example code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

init = np.array([
[0, 0, 255],
[0, 255, 0],
[255, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0],
])

c = KMeans(n_clusters=5,init=init,n_init=1,max_iter=1)
r = c.fit(img.reshape(-1, 3))
```

Comment: Are those seed colors for kmeans? Or the colors you need to evaluate in your actual input image?

Comment: Initial and final centers for kmeans and colors I need to evaluate :D I thought if kmeans is so good in clustering points it's good idea to use it as clustering for predefined center points. I know I miss point of whole algorithm, but nonetheless another idea is iterating over whole image, calculating delta between main colors and pixel color and then summing up by lowest delta.

Comment: wrong algorithm. kmeans is supposed to calculate those centroids. you just want nearest neighbor assignment. just calculate, for any point (all points), its distance to all centroids (np.linalg.norm of the difference), and then use `argmin` to find index of nearest centroid. -- I'm sure there's a function that does this somewhere, but eh, that's research effort (googling), which is your responsibility.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Great, finally I may break my mental blockers that forced me to find solution using KMeans. Thanks for advice.